# Low end impacts/thuds

Tags: bass, thud

Hi,

I am wondering if anyone has any tips on how to create nice "natural" sounding low end impact/thud type sounds to use as all purpose sweetener layers in impacts and so forth.

I have had some success with processed kickdrums and various bits from sound libraries but would love some ideas on how to create more of my own.

I heard one technique some people did is to bury a mic in the ground then jump on it, this sounds like it would give some good results, what kind of mic would you use for that? Contact mic?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be wary with processing too much low end stuff and layering lots of similar sounding stuff together as it can get very muddy and undefined very quickly. Keep it fairly simple with the tracklaying, perhaps add some sine wave stuff at a very low frequency in there. You might get more useful stuff using a something like a dynamic/condenser mic than a contact mic? Try sticking a D112 in the dirt and seeing what success you get with that ;)

Answer (score 3):

subharmonic synth, 
either the outboard dbx120 or the LowEnder plugin

Answer (score 0):

Andy is right on most of those accounts. One of the tricks I like is the Sub Generator. Have a sine wave tone generator and a noise gate on the same channel strip, and side chain whatever you want to be beefed up into the noise gate. When your sound plays, it will open the gate allowing the looow sine wave through.

Comment: But won't that emit the same note for the whole sound palette? I would prefer using a synth and playing with each sine tone individually.

Comment: Yes @Asimov, it would, i didn't know if he just wanted sub stuff that you would just perceive and not necessarily hear.